# Sign convention for writing heat released by or heat added to the system

Tags: thermodynamics, conventions

Suppose, we have two objects A and B. $Q$ amount of heat flows from A to B. So, will it be correct to write the following?

Heat released by A = $-Q$

Heat added to B = $Q$

I'm confused because we say this

Acceleration of car = $-5ms^{-2}$

Deceleration of car = $5ms^{-1}$

Do you understand my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first law of thermodynamics evaluates the change in internal energy (and kinetic and potential energy) of a system. Any energy added to a system that increases the internal energy of the system is considered positive, and any energy removed from the system that decreases the internal energy is considered negative.

The first law considers the heat added to the system as positive, and the heat removed from the system as negative. The first law considers the work done on the system as positive and the work done by the system as negative. The first law considers mass flow into the system as positive and mass flow out of the system as negative.

The heat added to the system is the negative of the heat lost by the surroundings.

Similarly for a mass, a force that "increases motion" causes positive acceleration and a force that "retards motion" causes negative acceleration (deacceleration).

In your question considering B as the system, the heat into B is +Q and the heat from A is -Q as you say. In your question you have acceleration negative and deacceleration positive, which is not correct considering the system as the mass affected by a force.

Answer (score 0):

In the  first law for a closed system heat into the system is positive. So it depends on whether you define A as the system or B as the system. If A is the system Q is negative for A and positive for B (which becomes the surroundings). If you define B as the system, it’s the other way around,

Hope this helps

Comment: If I consider the system as A+B, what will happen to the signs?

Comment: If the system is A + B then the heat transfer is internal to the system. Q in the first law is heat transfer between the system and surroundings, so if A+B is the system $Q=0$